# Firing an Event from inside custom control when enter key gets pressed

Tags: c#, winforms, events

I have a custom control and it needs to fire an event which will then be captured on the form and info processed.

Custom control is a list box. When i do left mouse click, then event on the form gets fired and i update the pieces perfectly.

When i am using up/down keys to look at the list box data and then hit ENTER, i am at this point firing the click event on list box but the form doesn't get notified. How can i fix this issue?

Event handler in the control

```
/// <summary>
        /// Event on the client when the selection has been made (click or hit enter)
        /// </summary>
        public event EventHandler ItemSelected
        {
            add { listBox.Click += value; }
            remove { listBox.Click -= value;  }
        }
```

List box click and keydown

```
private void listBox_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter && listBox.Items.Count > 0)
            {
                EventArgs x = e as EventArgs;

                listBox_Click(sender, x); //treat it as click to select the item 
            }
        }

        private void listBox_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (listBox.Items.Count > 0)
            {
                ComboBoxItem item = (ComboBoxItem)listBox.SelectedItem;
                if (item != null)
                {
                    _id = item.ID;
                    _code = item.Code;
                    //_text = item.Text;

                    //MessageBox.Show("U: " + _code + "-" + _texts);

                    base.Text = item.Text;  //item.DisplayField; 
                }
            }
            listBox.Visible = false;
        }
```

Event handler on the form

```
Private Sub YtxtDesc_ItemSelected(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles YtxtDesc.ItemSelected
        btnDesc.PerformClick()
    End Sub
```

Comment: You're not raising the event.  You're just calling the click method.

Comment: _Is_ the custom control a ListBox (by inheriting ListBox) or does it just contain a ListBox field?

Comment: It contains a listbox field. textbox is getting inherited.

Comment: changed to `InvokeOnClick(listBox, new EventArgs());` and it is firing. Other wise would have gone the reflection route.